# Why cannot I run the '%matplotlib inline' in pycharm's ipython console?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I used the Ipython Console, and it turns 3 errors like that:

```
KeyError: 'inline'

ValueError: Invalid GUI request 'inline', valid ones are:dict_keys(['pyglet', 'wx', 'gtk3', 'qt5', 'glut', 'none', 'tk', 'gtk', 'qt4', 'osx', 'qt'])

IPython.core.error.UsageError: Invalid GUI request 'inline', valid ones are:dict_keys(['pyglet', 'wx', 'gtk3', 'qt5', 'glut', 'none', 'tk', 'gtk', 'qt4', 'osx', 'qt'])
```

So should I choose one of these keys? or do something else to solve the problem?

p.s.
When I type the line below

```
%matplotlib --list
```

it shows：

```
Available matplotlib backends: ['gtk3', 'osx', 'qt5', 'notebook', 'inline', 'tk', 'gtk', 'qt4', 'wx', 'nbagg', 'qt']
```

the keyword"inline" is in the list. However, when I type

```
%matplotlib inline
```

it turns error.

Comment: PyCharm's IPython console is a text console. It cannot show images or interactive elements. Therefore the use of `%matplotlib inline` or `%matplotlib notebook` is not expected to work.

Comment: Also duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638043/embedded-charts-in-pycharm-ipython-console?rq=1

Comment: Thank you very much! At last I find it available in jupyter qt console why installed anaconda's IDE:)

Comment: If you have IPython inside PyCharms it would mean that you already have IPython installed (no need to do it again). You can try running [`jupyter qtconsole`](http://qtconsole.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to get an interactive interpreter with inline capability. Anaconda natively comes with the Spyder IDE, which uses the qt console. This may be an alternative to PyCharms.